# How to give fileName in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, filenames

I am uploading audio file from server, I want the name of files should be as I have

```
NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:firstName,lastName,pateintID]
```

and i want this file name to be passed to server like this

```
  [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".wav\"\r\n"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: What do you want to do by using [NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat...] ?

Comment: i send this filename to server with audio

Comment: I meaned that you have already got an autoreleased string via [NSString stringWithFormat:...]. And you want to create from this autoreleased string another autoreleased string with the same value and the same characteristics. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%,@%,%@",firstName,lastName,pateintID];
```

or this will output firstName_lastName_pateintID.mp3

```
NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%_@%_%@.mp3",firstName,lastName,pateintID];
```

---

If you want to upload the audio file use the [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) framework. Check their File Upload with Progress Callback example.

Comment: thanks it worked for me but how may pass this name to thing so that file should have this name

Comment: [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".wav\"\r\n"]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: @JaniBaloch, What you exactly want? Your question and comment both are different.

Comment: i want this file name to give the file which i am posting to server so i  have given the code which is sending server the name so how to that

Comment: @JaniBaloch I updated my answer. If I understand correctly you are trying to upload a file to server?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *fileName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%,@%,%@",firstName,lastName,pateintID];
```

and

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audio\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[fileName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];//file name is ur typed data
```

Audio file send to server

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".wav\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:AudioNSDataName]];  //AudioNSDataName is ur Audio NSData variable.
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: thanks file is uploaded sucessfully but when i check this file in mac with getinfo it shows as text file

Comment: thanks can i ask one thing this audio comes when we record the voice in a table view i have for e.g 3 audio files recordes so how can i store 3 that files and upload them at a time